# Error: App\Entity\User - bin/console make:user - Symfony 5.3.1

Tags: php, symfony5

Acabo de crear un proyecto nuevo en la última versión (5.3.1).

Todo bien hasta que creo la entidad de User que trae el framework:

**$** *php bin/console make:user*

Funciona bien pero me rompe el sitio. Me dice que el error está en la clase creada en src/Entity/User.php al definir la clase:

> Fatal error: Class App\Entity\User contains 1 abstract method and must
> therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
> (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername) in
> /home/fabri/Proyectos/Symfony/src/Entity/User.php on line 13

QUE ES LO SIGUIENTE:

```
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface {
```

Lo solucioné haciendo abstracta la clase pero esto me funcionó hasta que necesité instanciar esta entidad en un controller. Por lo que tuve que quitar el "abstract" pero esto me llevó de nuevo al mismo problema del comienzo.

Ojalá pueda solucionarlo ya que este framework me está gustando bastante. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me acaba de pasar lo mismo en este momento...
Agregué a la entidad las funciones:

```
public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Ojo, con esos getter y setter das a entender que asignas y recuperas el usuario, y lo estás haciendo con la contraseña...

Answer (score 0):

La interfaz `UserInterface` te obliga a implementar un método llamado `getUsername`.

A partir de Symfony 5.3 este método está marcado como obsoleto, así que es posible que tu entidad se haya generado con el método `getUserIdentifier`, ya que su nombre es mucho menos confuso.

Symfony lo que quiere es un método que vaya a existir siempre para que tú le digas cómo quieres que se identifiquen tus usuarios, y para no forzar a nadie a que este identificador sea un correo electrónico, un nombre de usuario, una id, etc, te ofrece este método.

Probablemente ya hayas elegido que el identificador sea el email, por ejemplo, cuando has ejecutado el maker de User, y tengas un método con este aspecto:

```php
/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUserIdentifier(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}
```

Como esta función será directamente sustituta de `getUsername` no me preocupo, de momento la implemento llamando a esta misma función, y así sé que obtendré el mismo resultado aunque mañana cambie de identificador a otra columna :-)

```
/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return $this->getUserIdentifier();
}
```